# Symmetrical encryption of email attributes with Devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attr-encrypted

I try to encrypt email attribute for User model. `email` is used by Devise.

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end`

`devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable`

To encryption I use `attr_encrypted` gem: https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted
I'd like to use this gem but I'm not attached to.
Actually I'm receiving a lot of issues related with this.

Does anyone has encrypted `email` attribute in Rails project where Devis was used, ideally using `attr_encrypted` ? What was your approach to that ?

Comment: I use attr_encrypted for some fields and I think it would be very tricky to get it working the way you want. What is the reason for encrypting email in the first place?

Comment: It's a client requirement, kind of formal stuff.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing. eMail addresses are valuable to hackers, it'd be nice to deny them that.